# like sql dependency  in shrepoint list

Tags: 2007

Can we do list dependency in sharepoint like 'sql dependency'.So we can fetch data in our catch if nothing change in list.can we do this?
Please help

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be wanting to look at "EventReceivers" in SharePoint to fulfil what you need.

If you are referring to Referential Integrity between two linked lists then this is only supported in SharePoint 2010.